# Polynomial divisor in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, prime-numbers, factoring

> **Q**: Find an odd prime $p$ for which $x-2$ is a divisor of $x^4 + x^3 + 3x^2 + x + 1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$.

I would rather not go through the Euclidean Algorithm for every mod $p$. Is there another way to find this particular prime?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: note that $x-2$ divides $f(x)$ specifically when $f(2) = 0$, so plug in $x=2$ and find a prime divisor of the result.

Comment: Rolf Hoyer has given a nice trick, but even doing this problem the "straightforward way" is quite short. We perform one polynomial division with remainder in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. The remainder will be a constant since the divisor has degree $1$, and then we pick a prime dividing the remainder.

Comment: @André3000 I think your method is just an elaboration of Rolf Hoyer's comment. It would be better if it were made into an answer, though.

Comment: @RolfHoyer It would be great if you or André3000 can turn your (respective) comments into an answer.